# Is it ok to say "so he basically did a dunk"?

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

Is the grammar ok?
Or should this be said in a different way like-

> so he basically performed a dunk

Which one is right?

Comment: He basically dunked it.

Comment: What about using dunk as a noun

Comment: You can say "he performed a dunk", but it's sorta prissy.

Comment: "He did a dunk" should be okay then

Comment: Take a look at [*slam dunk*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slam-dunk). You should add what you are trying to say, since there are at least two different contexts

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about basketball, (unless you are dipping biscuits in your tea).  Either verb is fine. They are both transitive verbs. A quick google search confirms that "perform a dunk" is a common in expressions like "How to perform a dunk", and "do a dunk" is also quite acceptable. You also can use "dunk" as a verb.

> So basically he dunked the ball.

Using "perform" suggests a more complex action.

Basketball is less common in Britain than in the USA, and dunk is probably more often used in the "biscuits in tea" sense, than in the Basketball sense.